# JsonSerializer dosen't deserialize any collection but deserializes all the rest of the object

Tags: c#, json, collections, deserialization, system.text.json

Assuming I have an array of the following JSON data:

```json
[
  {
    "foo": "somestring",
    "foo1": 2,
    "foo2": [
      "somestring1",
      "somestring2"
    ],
    "foo3": [
      {
        "bar1": 122312,
        "bar2": 3214324
      },
      {
        "bar3": 432432432,
        "bar4": 4324231
      }
    ]
  },
//more root array members...
]
```

I have created the following classes for the JSON to be deserialized into:

```cs
internal class StoredFoo
{
    [JsonPropertyName("foo")]
    public string Foo
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [JsonPropertyName("foo1")]
    public double Foo1
    {
        get; set;
    }
    [JsonPropertyName("foo2")]
    public List<string> Foo2 { get; } = new List<string>();
    [JsonPropertyName("foo3")]
    public List<StoredBar> Foo3 { get; } = new List<StoredBar>();
}

internal class StoredBar
{
    [JsonPropertyName("bar1")]
    public long Bar1
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [JsonPropertyName("bar2")]
    public long Bar2
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

(I apologize for being unable to use real names. part of the limitations of the project)

When I load up the JSON file and deserialize it:

```cs
string jsonFooData = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
IEnumerable<Foo> storedFoos = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Foo>>(jsonFooData);
```

Then `storedFoos` contains the objects, but `Foo2` and `Foo3` are empty, even when they shouldn't.

At first, I thought that this is because somehow the `= new List<string>()` occurs after the `JsonSerializer` had initialized the collection, effectively overriding it. But even removing the `= new List<string>()` statement, the collections are just set to `null` (without exception).

Why is that that `JsonSerializer` succeeds in deserializing into `foo` and `foo1` but not `foo2` and `foo3`?

Comment: Your `Foo2` and `Foo3` are get only properties so they are never initialised. Change them to be `get; set;` like the others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @zaitsman suggested, we can change the properties to be mutable.

If we want to populate read-only properties, we can use a public constructor.

```
public class StoredFoo
{
    [JsonPropertyName("foo")]
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("foo1")]
    public double Foo1 { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("foo2")]
    public List<string> Foo2 { get; } = new List<string>();

    [JsonPropertyName("foo3")]
    public List<StoredBar> Foo3 { get; } = new List<StoredBar>();

    public StoredFoo(string foo, double foo1, List<string> foo2, List<StoredBar> foo3)
        => (Foo, Foo1, Foo2, Foo3) = (foo, foo1, foo2, foo3);
}
```

If there is more than one constructor, use the [`JsonConstructor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconstructorattribute?view=net-5.0) attribute to define which constructor to use.